# Cannot access another Drive in Dual Drive Laptop (Two individual Drives not partitions)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a laptop with two Drives. One is SSD and the other is HDD. My ubuntu installation is on the SSD.

**Poblem:** I want to transfer my files to the HDD then install the dualboot  of windows and Debian but **I can see the HDD, even format it, but I do not have permissions to cut or paste into it**. What do I need to configure such that I can access it and after the dual boot, **I can still access it from both Operating Systems**.

Answer (score 0):

Run lsblk to see if the internal drive is mounted.  If it is, that will show the mount points.  If it's not being auto-mounted, you can mount it (see the mount man page).  If you left Windows in a hibernated state, the NTFS partitions won't be available.  You have to do a full shutdown from Windows first.